# NSNumberFormatter conversion remove the decimal for small values

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnumberformatter

Our quality-assurance team detect a defect. When they write `0.095` or `0,095` in a currency field, the `NSNumberFormatter` converts the content to `95`.

This is the code we're using:

```
+ (NSNumber *) getNumberWithDecimalFromString:(NSString*) theSource
{
    if ([TSCommons isEmpty:theSource])
        return [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:0];

    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

    if ([theSource rangeOfString:@","].location != NSNotFound) {
        [formatter setDecimalSeparator:@","];
        [formatter setCurrencyDecimalSeparator:@"."];
    } else if ([theSource rangeOfString:@"."].location != NSNotFound) {
        [formatter setDecimalSeparator:@"."];
        [formatter setCurrencyDecimalSeparator:@"."];
    }
    NSNumber *tmp = [formatter numberFromString:theSource];

    [formatter release];
    return [tmp retain];
}
```

The locale is `es_ES`

Any idea about this unexpected behavior?

To introduce more information about this problem, because come back again after the last XCode update I prepared a test

```
- (void) testNumberFormatter
{
    NSLog(@"%f",[[TSCommons getNumberWithDecimalFromString:@"41,1"] doubleValue]);
    NSLog(@"%f",[[TSCommons getNumberWithDecimalFromString:@"41,12342"] doubleValue]);
    NSLog(@"%f",[[TSCommons getNumberWithDecimalFromString:@"41,12"] floatValue]);
    NSLog(@"%f",[[TSCommons getNumberWithDecimalFromString:@"41,123"] floatValue]);
    NSLog(@"%f",[[TSCommons getNumberWithDecimalFromString:@"41,1234"] floatValue]);
    NSLog(@"%f",[[TSCommons getNumberWithDecimalFromString:@"41,1234234"] doubleValue]);
}
```

The result on the Console is the following:

41.100000

41.123420

41.119999

**41123.000000**

41.123402

41.123423

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you check the string value of theSource before using [formatter numberFromString:theSource]? How do you output NSNumber? Tried at home and it works.

Comment: If I apply to the NSNumber the doubleValue or floatValue the result is 95. If I debug the NSNumber description is long(95)

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString* theSource = @"0.095";
        NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

        if ([theSource rangeOfString:@","].location != NSNotFound) {
            [formatter setDecimalSeparator:@","];
            [formatter setCurrencyDecimalSeparator:@"."];
        } else if ([theSource rangeOfString:@"."].location != NSNotFound) {
            [formatter setDecimalSeparator:@"."];
            [formatter setCurrencyDecimalSeparator:@"."];
        }
        NSNumber *tmp = [formatter numberFromString:theSource];
        NSLog(@"get Number %@ - %lf %lf", tmp, [theSource doubleValue], [tmp floatValue]);
```

// output get Number 0.095 - 0.095000 0.095000